# Do C object files have to have to the same name as the corresponding header file?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, header-files

As the title asks, do object files have to have the same name as the header file in order to be properly linked?

ie. could I have a header file 'foo.h' and call it 'bar.o' and still have it properly link?

In source code, I would still need to write `include "foo.h"` so I speculate that the linker will reject this since the two do not share the same name.

Comment: You can name your files the way you want.

Comment: Note that a header file does not usually produce an object file when compiled on its own.  And the same disconnect between names applies to source files and object files:  `gcc -o tangent.o cosine.c` creates a file `tangent.c` from the source file `cosine.c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that says a particular header file is associated with a particular object file.

A header file typically contains only declarations.  It does *not* say anything regarding where the associated definitions reside.  You could have two source files such as main.c and foo.c and have both use a header file called common.h.  When you compile, you could then create main.o and foo.o and link them together into "myprogram".